# Unattended Nginx install fails with 400 Bad Request errors, but command line install is fine. 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, nginx, vagrant

I am trying to put together a Vagrant & VirtualBox VM that uses provisioning scripts to perform unattended installations of all needed software after the initial `vagrant up`. This is something I've done before without issues, but on this build I've been hitting `400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]` with a frequency I haven't seen before.

The errors start in the first `apt-get upgrade` which is run as one of the first provisioning steps.

I was running this on initial start up:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

which has now morphed into this:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get -y upgrade --with-new-pkgs --fix-missing
```

Both versions included the `400 Bad Request` errors in their output.

For the Nginx install itself I started with this:

```
sudo apt-get -y install nginx
```

Which has become

```
sudo apt-get -y install nginx --with-new-pkgs --fix-missing
```

with either version, the outcome is the same -  four 400 errors in the midst of the output like this:

```
    default: Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libfontconfig1 amd64 2.13.1-2ubuntu3
    default:   400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
```

followed by the "Unable to correct missing packages" message, which lists the same packages and their
***perfectly good and reachable urls***:

```
... 
    default: Fetched 2,827 kB in 9s (300 kB/s)
    default: Unable to correct missing packages.
    default: E
    default: :
    default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/libfontconfig1_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
    default: E
    default: :
    default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg8-empty/libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
    default: E
    default: :
    default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwebp/libwebp6_0.6.1-2_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
    default: E
    default: :
    default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxpm/libxpm4_3.5.12-1_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
    default: E
    default: :
    default: Aborting install.
```

I've added steps to the provisioner to do an `apt-get clean`, to delete all files in the `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory, deleted the `/etc/apt/sources.list`, provided an alternate `/etc/apt/sources.list` - none of these steps resolved a single 400 error.

However, if I let the `vagrant up` run until the "Aborting install" failure then `vagrant ssh` into the VM, when I run either `sudo apt-get -y install nginx` or `sudo apt-get -y install nginx --with-new-pkgs --fix-missing` the install happens successfully without a single 400 error.

What can I do to make this installation work using the unattended provisioners?

EDIT: This is the output at the beginning of the installer. I am suspicious that the `35 not upgraded` may be part of the issue:

```
    default: Starting NGINX install.
    default: Reading package lists...
    default: Building dependency tree...
    default: Reading state information...
    default: The following additional packages will be installed:
    default:   fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libgd3 libjbig0
    default:   libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
    default:   libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream libtiff5
    default:   libwebp6 libx11-6 libx11-data libxcb1 libxpm4 nginx-common nginx-core
    default: Suggested packages:
    default:   libgd-tools fcgiwrap nginx-doc ssl-cert
    default: The following NEW packages will be installed:
    default:   fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libgd3 libjbig0
    default:   libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
    default:   libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream libtiff5
    default:   libwebp6 libx11-6 libx11-data libxcb1 libxpm4 nginx nginx-common nginx-core
    default: 0 upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
    default: Need to get 3,163 kB of archives.
    default: After this operation, 11.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Comment: Try again in a few hours, the mirrors may be syncing right now.  This has nothing to do with nginx though, and more that when your system is requesting packages from the mirrors the *mirrors* are rejecting the request - wait for the mirrors to sync up first, and then try again (this is usually a temporary issue I've observed)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWard, I will do that. This actually was occurring on Friday, but I don't have a record of the exact packages. Hopefully that's it, I will try again in the morning.

Comment: Actually, I must be tired. The thing I'm stuck on is why the command doesn't work in the script when it works from the command line, especially with that error?